# Parse config files

Tags: php, regex

What is best way to parse text(config files) where are diffirent "styles" to set variable:

```
 var_name = "Content" // comment
 var_name2 = Content // comment
 set var_name3 "Content" // comment
 Var_name4=Content // comment
```

I need only var_name and content, ignore "set" and "// ..."

Comment: Why are you so liberal in your config style syntax? Pick a syntax and require the users to follow it.

Comment: What have you researched so far? Why aren't you editing it into a consistent style and just use one of the many many ini parsers?

Comment: use xml for your config syntax free form text file configs are nightmares to parse. structured text files such as xml are perfect for this

Comment: @Barmar i need to parse multiple game servers config files, it's impossible to change syntax :(.

Comment: Do you have to use the same parser for all of them?

Comment: @Barmar For the last one i can use parse_ini_file, but for rest i don't know good regex.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use a regexp to parse them all:

```
^\s*(?:set\s+)?(\w+)(?:\s*=\s*)?"?([^"]*?)"?\s*(?://.*)?$
```

`$1` is the variable name, `$2` is the value.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?37d71)

This has one bug: If you put `//` inside the quoted content, it will be treated as the beginning of a comment.

Comment: Thanks! But i can't test this using php: `preg_match('/^\s*(?:set\s+)?(\w+)(?:\s*=\s*)?"?([^"]*?)"?\s*(?://.*)?$/' , $test, $match);` gives me warning: Unknown modifier '"', using '^\s*(?:set\s+)?(\w+)(?:\s*=\s*)?"?([^"]*?)"?\s*(?://.*)?$' : Unknown modifier '"'

Comment: Use a different delimiter than `/` around your regexp, or escape the `/` inside the regexp.